# Optimal generation of numpy associative array with subarrays and variable length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, associative-array

I have Python-generated data, of the type

```
fa      fb      fc
fa1     fb1     [fc01, fc02,..., fc0m]
fa2     fb2     [fc11, fc12,..., fc1m]
...     ...     ...
fan     fbn     [fcn1, fcn2,..., fcnm]
```

I need to create a Python-compatible data structure to store it, maximizing ease of creation, and minimizing memory usage and read/write time. I need to be able to identify columns via field names (i.e. retrieve `fa1` with something like `data['fa'][0]`). `fa` values are ints, and `fb` and `fc` are floats. Neither `m` nor `n` are known before runtime, but are known before data is inserted into the data structure, and do not change. `m` will not exceed 1000, and `n` won't exceed 10000. Data is generated one row at a time.

Until now, I've used a numpy associative array, `asar`, of `dtype=[('f0,'i2'), ('f1','f8'), ('f2', 'f8', (m))]`. However, since I can't just add a new row to a numpy array without deleting and recreating it each time a row is added, I've been using a separate counting variable `ind_n`, creating `asar` with `asar = numpy.zeroes(n, dtype=dtype)`, overwriting `asar[ind_n]`'s zeroes with the data to be added, then incrementing `ind_n` until it reaches `n`. This works, but it seems like there must be a better solution (or at least one that allows me to eliminate `ind_n`). Is there a standard way to create the skeleton of `asar` (perhaps with something like `np.zeroes()`), then insert each line of data into the first nonzero row? Or a way to convert a standard python nested list to an associative array, once the nested list has been completely generated? (I know this conversion can definitely be done, but run into issues (e.g. `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`) when converting the subarray, when I attempt it.)

Comment: I don't see any problem with using that record indexing variable.  That's a common way of filling a `zeros` array.  As for creating the array from a list, look at the structure of `asar.tolist()`.  The nested list should imitate that, paying special attention to the nesting of lists and tuples.  Another good way of filling a structured array is to copy values field by field.  `asar['fa'] = ....`, `asar['fc']=np.ones((n,m))`, etc.  With only 3 fields, that iteration will be much faster than iterating on `n` records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [39]: n, m = 5, 3
In [41]: dt=np.dtype([('f0','i2'), ('f1','f8'), ('f2', 'f8', (m))])

In [45]: asar = np.zeros(n, dt)
In [46]: asar
Out[46]: 
array([(0, 0., [0., 0., 0.]), (0, 0., [0., 0., 0.]),
       (0, 0., [0., 0., 0.]), (0, 0., [0., 0., 0.]),
       (0, 0., [0., 0., 0.])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i2'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8', (3,))])
```

Filling by field:

```
In [49]: asar['f0'] = np.arange(5)
In [50]: asar['f1'] = np.random.rand(5)
In [51]: asar['f2'] = np.random.rand(5,3)
In [52]: asar
Out[52]: 
array([(0, 0.45120412, [0.86481761, 0.08861093, 0.42212446]),
       (1, 0.63926708, [0.43788684, 0.89254029, 0.90637292]),
       (2, 0.33844457, [0.80352251, 0.25411018, 0.315124  ]),
       (3, 0.24271258, [0.27849709, 0.9905879 , 0.94155558]),
       (4, 0.89239324, [0.1580938 , 0.52844036, 0.59092695])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i2'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8', (3,))])
```

Generating a list with matching nesting:

```
In [53]: alist = [(i,i,[10]*3) for i in range(5)]
In [54]: np.array(alist, dt)
Out[54]: 
array([(0, 0., [10., 10., 10.]), (1, 1., [10., 10., 10.]),
       (2, 2., [10., 10., 10.]), (3, 3., [10., 10., 10.]),
       (4, 4., [10., 10., 10.])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i2'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8', (3,))])
```

Obviously you could do:

```
for i, row in enumerate(alist):
    asar[i] = row
```

`enumerate` is a nice idiomatic way of generating an index along with a value.  But then so is `range(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know `n` at the time you create the first record your solution is essentially correct.

You can use `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros` saving a bit (but not much) time.

If you feel bad about `ind_n` you can create an array iterator instead.

```
>>> m = 5
>>> n = 7
>>> dt = [('col1', 'i2'), ('col2', float), ('col3', float, (m,))]
>>> data = [(np.random.randint(10), np.random.random(), np.random.random((m,))) for _ in range(n)]
>>> 
>>> rec = np.empty((n,), dt)
>>> irec = np.nditer(rec, op_flags=[['readwrite']], flags=['c_index'])
>>> 
>>> for src in data:
...     # roughly equivalent to list.append:
...     next(irec)[()] = src
...     print()
...     # getting the currently valid part:
...     print(irec.operands[0][:irec.index+1])
... 

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])]

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])
 (6, 0.82350335, [0.57971597, 0.61270304, 0.05280996, 0.03702404, 0.99159465])]

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])
 (6, 0.82350335, [0.57971597, 0.61270304, 0.05280996, 0.03702404, 0.99159465])
 (3, 0.06565234, [0.88921842, 0.21097122, 0.83276431, 0.01824657, 0.49105466])]

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])
 (6, 0.82350335, [0.57971597, 0.61270304, 0.05280996, 0.03702404, 0.99159465])
 (3, 0.06565234, [0.88921842, 0.21097122, 0.83276431, 0.01824657, 0.49105466])
 (2, 0.69806099, [0.87749632, 0.22119474, 0.25623813, 0.26587436, 0.04772489])]

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])
 (6, 0.82350335, [0.57971597, 0.61270304, 0.05280996, 0.03702404, 0.99159465])
 (3, 0.06565234, [0.88921842, 0.21097122, 0.83276431, 0.01824657, 0.49105466])
 (2, 0.69806099, [0.87749632, 0.22119474, 0.25623813, 0.26587436, 0.04772489])
 (1, 0.77573727, [0.44359522, 0.62471617, 0.65742177, 0.38889958, 0.13901824])]

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])
 (6, 0.82350335, [0.57971597, 0.61270304, 0.05280996, 0.03702404, 0.99159465])
 (3, 0.06565234, [0.88921842, 0.21097122, 0.83276431, 0.01824657, 0.49105466])
 (2, 0.69806099, [0.87749632, 0.22119474, 0.25623813, 0.26587436, 0.04772489])
 (1, 0.77573727, [0.44359522, 0.62471617, 0.65742177, 0.38889958, 0.13901824])
 (0, 0.45797521, [0.79193395, 0.69029592, 0.0541346 , 0.49603146, 0.36146384])]

[(9, 0.07368308, [0.44691665, 0.38875103, 0.83522137, 0.39281718, 0.62078615])
 (6, 0.82350335, [0.57971597, 0.61270304, 0.05280996, 0.03702404, 0.99159465])
 (3, 0.06565234, [0.88921842, 0.21097122, 0.83276431, 0.01824657, 0.49105466])
 (2, 0.69806099, [0.87749632, 0.22119474, 0.25623813, 0.26587436, 0.04772489])
 (1, 0.77573727, [0.44359522, 0.62471617, 0.65742177, 0.38889958, 0.13901824])
 (0, 0.45797521, [0.79193395, 0.69029592, 0.0541346 , 0.49603146, 0.36146384])
 (6, 0.85225039, [0.62028917, 0.4895316 , 0.00922578, 0.66836154, 0.53082779])]
```